# Add newline to string, cross-platform

Tags: python, linux, windows, cross-platform, newline

I am generating some text in my application. Since the text is part of a bigger message, sometimes I need to add newlines, sometimes not:

```
NEWLINE = '\n'  # TODO: how to define this cross-platform? Can I use os.linesep?

def get_txt(add_newline=False):
    txt = 'Hello'
    if add_newline:
        txt += NEWLINE
    return txt
```

This could be used as follows:

```
def get_message():
    msg = get_txt(True)
    msg += get_txt(True)
    msg += get_txt(False)
    return msg
```

Which would return:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello (no newline here)
```

How can I define `NEWLINE` in a cross-platform manner? Or better yet, is there a function in the standard library (or included in python) which can append a newline to a string? (not necessarily when printing, just append a newline to the string in memory). The newline used should be the right one for the platform were python is running

Comment: Did you try `os.linesep` as you mentioned in the comment in your code?

Comment: @IronFist: I have no Windows machine to test, and I have seen references agains using `os.linesep` (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21636213/647991). I would like to know what is the canonical way of embedding newlines in strings, without printing. What I need is probably what print does internally with the newlines, but I am not sure.

Comment: So...that should answer it...No?...it's an implementation details that you don't need to be concern with...Depending on which platform you are writing the file, Python will make sure to end the line with the appropriate line ending.

Comment: @IronFist: No, it doesn't. How do I build a string in memory with newline separators in a cross-platform way? Should I use `\n` in all platforms? I guess my root question is: are in-memory newline separators different in windows and linux, or does this difference only exist on IO backed data (files and terminals)?

Comment: reading that link suggests to me that you should just use `'\n'` and python will handle the conversion on windows when(if) it's ever needed... eg if written to a file?

Comment: @JamesKent: yep, that's the conclussion that I am arriving at too ...

Comment: i can confirm that on my windows machine, if i build a string in memory using only `'\n'` and then write it to file, python does replace it (checked with hex editor) and i've never had any issue using a simple newline with any other library either...

Comment: @JamesKent: Ok, sounds right. I've always been using `\n` for my newlines, but this is the first time I am building strings in memory targeting a windows machine (my client has windows, but I can not test it myself unfortunately). Maybe you can add that as an answer.

Comment: and of course, you'll add "test new-line conversion" to the top of your validation list, eh? ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've always just used the newline character `'\n'` to signify a linebreak, although windows uses a newline and a carriage return character, I tested on my windows machine (python 3.4) building a string in memory and then writing it to file, while in memory it stays as a single character (`'\n'`) however when written to file it gets converted into two characters to have the correct line ending on windows.
up till now I have yet to come across a single library that had an issue with this.

Answer (score 31):

You can try with this:

```
import os
print(os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python** uses `\n` to signify a line break.

**Python** automatically translates `\n` to the proper newline character based on the platform.

You can also try

```
import os
print (os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print your message to have it displaying as new line.

```
get_txt()
msg = get_message()
print(msg)
```

will give you:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Just need make sure to print to file.