# Newline seperator in cross-platform programming

Tags: python, cross-platform, newline

I'm sorry if my question isn't well described.
I'm learning Python specifically at the moment, but answers in other languages will also be useful to me.
I want to write with cross-platform in mind, and I'm confused about newline character usage.
So far I have used '\n' in Java, C and C++ in both windows and linux (ubuntu/lubuntu).
Is it safe to use '\n'? or should I define a "NEWLINE" variable and assign it to a different character?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Python use "\n". When writing a file, Python respects the platform's conventions. When reading a textfile, it knows how to handle different conventions, so that when you get a file from another OS you won't have trouble reading it. If you are writing a file that is going to be read by *another* language on *another* OS and that other language is picky, then it is necessary to know what that language is picky about. There isn't a universal solution to this, but my advice would be to concentrate on learning Python and don't let such side issues distract you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add newline to string, cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654493/add-newline-to-string-cross-platform)

Comment: @BoarGules So what I understand from you comment, is that Python fixes that for me? that is, if I simply use '\n' it will work even if used on a different OS than mine? I have seen the question Sergey mentioned but although they showed the solution with os.linesep, they didn't explain whether I should use it. May I trouble you by asking you to refer me to the documentation?  I will not focus on that don't worry, but I do want to understand. I'm a CS student, and I'd like to understand even if I shouldn't try to. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The behaviour is documented in the description of the optional parameter `newline` to the built-in function `open()` at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. The default value for this is `None` which nearly always does what you want without having to think about it.