# What is os.linesep for?

Tags: python, file-io, separator, platform-independent

Python's os module contains a value for a platform specific line separating string, but the docs explicitly say not to use it when writing to a file:

> Do not use os.linesep as a line terminator when writing files opened in text mode (the default); use a single '\n' instead, on all platforms.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep)

[Previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636213/why-you-shouldnt-use-os-linesep-when-editing-on-text-mode) have explored why you *shouldn't* use it in this context, but then what context is it useful for? When should you use the line separator, and for what?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> the docs explicitly say not to use it when writing to a file

Not exactly. The doc says not to use it in **text** mode.

The `os.linesep` is used when you want to iterate through the lines of a text file. The internal scanner recognises the `os.linesep` and replaces it by a single `\n`.

For illustration, we write a binary file which contains 3 lines separated by `\r\n` (Windows delimiter):

```
import io

filename = "text.txt"

content = b'line1\r\nline2\r\nline3'
with io.open(filename, mode="wb") as fd:
    fd.write(content)
```

The content of the binary file is:

```
with io.open(filename, mode="rb") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        print(repr(line))
```

*NB: I used the `"rb"` mode to read the file as a binary file.*

I get:

```
b'line1\r\n'
b'line2\r\n'
b'line3'
```

If I read the content of the file using the text mode, like this:

```
with io.open(filename, mode="r", encoding="ascii") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        print(repr(line))
```

I get:

```
'line1\n'
'line2\n'
'line3'
```

The delimiter is replaced by `\n`.

The `os.linesep` is also used in write mode. Any `\n` character is converted to the system default line separator: `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on POSIX, etc.

With the `io.open` function you can force the line separator to whatever you want.

Example: how to write a Windows text file:

```
with io.open(filename, mode="w", encoding="ascii", newline="\r\n") as fd:
    fd.write("one\ntwo\nthree\n")
```

If you read this file in text mode like this:

```
with io.open(filename, mode="rb") as fd:
    content = fd.read()
    print(repr(content))
```

You get:

```
b'one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\n'
```

Answer (score 7):

As you know, reading and writing files in text mode in python converts the platform specific line separator to '\n' and vice versa. But if you would read a file in binary mode, no conversion takes place. Then you can explicitly convert the line endings using `string.replace(os.linesep, '\n')`. This can be useful if a file (or stream or whatever) contains a combination of binary and text data.

Comment: It wouldn't work if encoding is ascii incompatible. `len('\n'.encode('utf-16'))` is 4